# Can not display correct character utf8 in jsp when get data from sql server 2012

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jsp, servlets

I'm using jsp connect to sql server 2012, I have try to get data from my db but some characters unicode was broken. I have try a lot of ways but it can not correct result.

In my jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
   request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
%>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Server.xml of tomcat:

```
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Collation in sql server is:

```
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

However text font still broken as following:

```
xin chào t?t c? các b?n, vui đư?c làm quen v?i các b?n
```

How to fix this error when get data from my database ?

Thank so much !!

Comment: First thing to do: add more diagnostics so you can tell whether the problem is getting the results from your database, or displaying them to the user. Log each received character's UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet: that string is result I recieved from my db, I notice more is my string is varchar, is not nvarchar

Comment: Unless you log each UTF-16 code unit, we can't tell whether the "?" is just a failure to display a different character, or genuinely a question mark. That could be important. Additionally, if you're saying that that string isn't what's shown in the resulting page but is a result of logging, you should make that *really* clear in your question. Ideally, take servlets out of the picture entirely - can you reproduce this problem in a console application? (Again, logging the UTF-16 code units so that the console font and encoding are irrelevant.)